# Sort a list of names containing numbers by the numeric value

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort a list which includes a set such as;

100.avi

10000.avi

10002.avi

1003.avi ....

I need to do some process using the files in numeric order. If I use `sorted` it does not care about the values, it sorts on the first character, second character, and so on - string sorting.

I tried to use [:-4] but I tried to do this on the list not the element of the list. Because it is late when I have the element. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sorted(list_of_filenames, key=lambda name: int(name[:-4]))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [sorting function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to extract the number from each element of the list and use it as the comparison key. You'd need to convert it to `int` to ensure it compares like number:

```
>>> lst = ['100.avi', '10000.avi', '10002.avi', '1003.avi']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.', 1)[0]))
['100.avi', '1003.avi', '10000.avi', '10002.avi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all the strings of your given *list* are ended in `.avi` extension, you could use a *slicing* feature.

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x[:-4]))
```

Comment: If you assign the result of `sorted()` back to `lst` you could as well use `lst.sort()`.